# pyproj with Python 2.7.9 on win7 64 gives "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Tags: c++, windows, python-2.7, grib

I need to install pyproj on my machine and it give the above mentioned error. I guess it would be the same for other python components that are using C++ code:

My situation:

Win 7 64 bit running.

installed:

- VS 2008 express
- MS VS patch for python 2.7 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505
- Python Setup Tools available here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads

set up the path variables and set

VS90COMNTOOLS
Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools

I try to install the pyproj: http://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/

but it returns the same error:

```
  File "msvc9compiler.py", line 271, in  query_vcvarsall raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat") distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

the purpose of this is to get the pygrib package running: http://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/docs/index.html

Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Does "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" exist on your machine? Do you use Python x64 or win32?

Comment: Thanks for the comment: I use python 64 bit and there is no such file in this location nor elsewhere on the computer. where can I get such a file?

Comment: i found it in : AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0

Comment: I copied the file to the indicated location and now other error occurs: File "D:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsall raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

Comment: ValueError: [u'path']

Comment: no ideas? I am stucked.

Answer (score 2):

You can install this without needing to compile it by using a [precompiled Python wheel](http://pythonwheels.com/). You can find a compatible wheel for pyproj at [this page containing unofficial wheels](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

You are specifically looking for `pyproj-1.9.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`. Once you download the `whl` file, you can install it with pip using

```
pip install pyproj-1.9.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

And that will install it for you, skipping the compilation process.